# Solving a first order quasilinear PDEs using the idea of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was considering the following problem:

$$u_t+uu_x=1$$

Then I put this in the form of $\frac{du}{dt}=1,$ $\frac{dx}{dt}=u$ and deduced that the general form would be $$u=t+f(x+\frac{1}{2}t^2−ut)$$

for some arbitrary function $f$ that should be determined via initial condition. Up to this step I am confident that I am correct.

*Problem*:

So as a sanity check I wanted to make sure the $u$ I found indeed would satisfy the PDE. So I calculated its partial derivatives as follows:

$u_t=1+(t-u)f'(x+\frac{1}{2}t^2−ut)$, $u_x=f'(x+\frac{1}{2}t^2−ut).$ Plug everything in I have that

$$u_t+uu_x=1+tf'$$

But I was expecting it to be just $1$? Where have I gone wrong? Have I used the chain rule on partial derivatives incorrectly? Many thanks in advance!

*Edit*

I saw where my mistake is now. I was meant to partial differentiate rhs as well since $u$ lies in the argument.

Comment: I believe this is **quasi**, not semi linear.

Comment: @K.defaoite Oops, you are right! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but it seems that

$u_t=1+(t-u-u_t t)f'(x+\frac{1}{2}t^2−ut)$

and

$u_x=(1 - u_x t)f'(x+\frac{1}{2}t^2−ut)$,

so that

$u_t+uu_x = 1 + (1-u_t -uu_x)tf'(x+\frac{1}{2}t^2−ut)$,

hence

$(u_t+uu_x-1)[1+tf'(x+\frac{1}{2}t^2−ut)]=0$.

Since $f$ is an arbitrary function, the equation above implies $u_t+uu_x-1=0$.

Comment: I got similar, too!